# Stop a thread after all instructions has finished in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to create a thread every second that upload a photo to a server.

This piece of code should upload the photo to Google Cloud Platform using the google.cloud library.
 My problem is that I want to send 1 frame per second shot by the picamera. 
Without threading, the delay is too much. With the code below it creates a new thread not every second but every time the camera gets a new frame. It also does not "destroy" the thread after it finished all operations. Could you please help me figuring this out? Thanks and sorry for my english and for my bad code.

```
if int(round(time.time() * 1000)) - oldtime > 1000 & serConn:
            oldtime = time.time()
            thread = Thread(target = upload, args = (stream.read(), ))
            thread.start()
            thread.join()
```

upload function:

```
def upload(img):
    image = vision_client.image(content=img)

    # Performs label detection on the image file
    labels = image.detect_labels()
    for label in labels:
        if label.description == "signage":
            ser.write("0")
            print("Stop")
        else:
            ser.write("1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the `join` function call. This will cause the calling block to stop and wait for the thread to terminate. Also, I recommend using module `time` to sleep the main thread between shots. Try this:

```
import time

while True:
    if serConn:
        thread = Thread(target = upload, args = (stream.read(), ))
        thread.start()
    time.sleep(1)
```